# Sectioning data in a ListView

Tags: react-native, redux

Say you have a list of `People` incoming from your API.

```
[{content: 'John'},
{content: 'Tim'},
{content: 'Harry J. Epstein'}]
```

And you're looking to put people who are first-name-basis friends (John and Tim) under a section 'Friends' and people who are not (Harry J. Epstein) under 'Contacts'.

Tapping a friend selects them with a blue highlight, but tapping a 'contact' selects them with a red highlight.

Would the proper approach be to take the incoming data from the API, add a `type: 'Friend', ...` or `type: 'Contact', ...` around it, and section based on that type with separate a `FriendItem` and `ContactItem` class so I can split the highlighting function?

I've got a bunch of just basic ListView code that does this exact approach, but I'm basically looking for the easy way out, like Angulars `ng-repeat` equivalent.

So what's the React Native version of

```
var friends = api.getFriends()
var contacts = api.getContacts()

<div ng-repeat="friend in friends" ng-click="highlightFriend()"> ... </div>
<div ng-repeat="contact in contacts" ng-click="highlightContact()"> ... </div>
```

I'm struggling to understand how to split it. Do I need a `FriendsPage`, `FriendsItem`, and `ContactsItem`? Or put everything into one array in `FriendsPage` and use a `FriendsItem` that checks if it's a friend or contact and adds a function separately?

I feel like I'm slightly lost coming from MVC. I've got Redux running too, if there's an easy way using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice example on how you can create section-dependent rows: https://github.com/spoeck/ListViewExample

The idea is basically to create the data blob properly, which is a bit tricky, and then in your `renderRow` callback, check the `sectionID` parameter:

```
_renderRow(rowData: any, sectionID: any, rowID: number) {

    if (sectionID === this.data[0].section) {
        return <MyFriends />

    } else if (sectionID === this.data[1].section) {
        return <MyContacts />

    }else{ 
     // ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try [SectionList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html)

> Use the new FlatList or SectionList component instead. Besides
>   simplifying the API, the new list components also have significant
>   performance enhancements, the main one being nearly constant memory
>   usage for any number of rows.